# No output in terminal while running node js server in VS code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

As a part of creating a simple login page in node js, I tried to run a simple server. But I found no output in my terminal expect the file path. I'm using a really old machine. It's
an Intel Pentiumm core 2 duo with 4GB ram. It seems to be hung to give output.I tried running the code out of vs code, in the traditional command prompt. But there's no output.

[image: Here's my empty terminal screenshot]

Comment: I don't see any `console.log` calls

Comment: What makes you think your node process is not running? did you check task manager and node process pid.
also there is a chance that your server is running but since you haven't used any console.log message you are not able to see that try using this `app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server is listening on port 3000");
});`

Comment: Thank you so much brother... I just realised how stupid I was . I didn't even checked for console.log. Ngl, you made my day.